Is stopping time for martingale with continuous trajectories finite almost surely?
Let $(M_t,F_t)_t$ be martingale with continuous trajectories such that $M_t - t^{3/2}$ is also a martingale, and $M_0=3$. Let $T=\inf\{t : \lvert M_t \rvert = 8\}$. Show that $T$ is finite almost surely.
I know this is true for Brownian motion, but the my proof relies on the fact that I know probability density function for Brownian motion.
Is stopping time for martingale with continuous trajectories finite almost surely?

It is basic courtesy in this site to accept and upvote answers that you find useful. It is the only way you reward the user who has taken time to answer your question. You have not done so in almost all of your posts. This is a problem that is plaguing the site and I'm afraid it is one of the reasons that it is becomming unpopular and more like quora. There are less and less upvotes to encourage more participators and there are more downvotes for no particular reason.

This is false. Suppose $M_t$ is Brownian motion started at $M_0=3$ and let $\tau = \inf \{t > 0 \, : \, |M_t| = 7\}$, so that $M_{t \land \tau}$ is a martingale with continuous trajectories. Then, for this martingale, we have that $P(T < \infty) = 0$, disproving your claim.
Edit: If we add the condition that $M_t^2 - t^{3/2}$ is a martingale this becomes true. Indeed, in this case $\langle M \rangle_t = t^{3/2}$; i.e. $M_t$ is a continuous martingale with deterministic quadratic variation. This implies that $M_t = B_{t^{3/2}}$ for some Brownian motion $B_t$ (see e.g. here). Then, the proof follows immediately from the proof of the same fact for Brownian motion.

see edit please

@romperextremeabuser Updated my answer to account for that.

@romperextremeabuser does this answer your question?
